# How I can connect and color the lines based on the ID in R?

Tags: r, visualization, markov-chains

I want to connect the points with lines and also I want to color the lines based on the ID. I can summarize what I have tried with the following examples:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- array(runif(100*15, 0,1), dim=c(3,5,100))

id <- sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE)

plot(c(0,100), c(-0.2,2), type="n", ylab="", xlab="")
for ( i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:1){
    for( k in 1:4){
      indx<- which(id==k)
      points((1:100)[indx], 0.2*data[i,j,indx] +0.15*(i==2)+ 0.3*(i==3),
             col=if(k==1){"red"}else if(
               k==2) { "green3" } else if (k==3){"brown"} else {"blue"}, pch=20, cex=0.8)
      
    }
    lines((1:100), 0.2*data[i,j,]+0.15*(i==2)+ 0.3*(i==3),
          
          col="grey", lty=i)
  }
  
}
```

This piece of code plots the points and I connect the points with a grey line. As you can see, it is not easy to see/observe the transitions from, say, for example, k=1 to k=2 especially when the sample size is larger. Therefore, I removed the points and want to include only the lines. When I try the following code; it only gives me the lines when k=4.

```
plot(c(0,100), c(-0.2,2), type="n", ylab="", xlab="")
for ( i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:1){
    for( k in 1:4){
      indx<- which(id==k)
    }
    lines((1:100)[indx], 0.2*data[i,j,indx]+0.15*(i==2)+ 0.3*(i==3),
          
          col=k, lty=i)
  }
  
}
```

I know why I am getting this because it is overwriting the previous k values and I need to put the lines() function within the for loop of "k". When I try this with the following code, I am getting four colored lines for each "i", but this is also not what I want. Is there a way to connect and color the lines based on the id? Thanks.

```
plot(c(0,100), c(-0.2,2), type="n", ylab="", xlab="")
for ( i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:1){
    for( k in 1:4){
      indx<- which(id==k)
      lines((1:100)[indx], 0.2*data[i,j,indx]+0.15*(i==2)+ 0.3*(i==3),
            col=k, lty=i)
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: If you are connecting pairs of points I would imagine that you would be using `segments` rather than `lines`. I would also imagine that you might get a more immediate illustration if your example were a few hundred times smaller.

Comment: I am positive this can be accomplished with ggplot2 and geom_line.  I highly recommend using that R package.  Not only will you be able to solve this problem, but also your plot will look better.  Start here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html

Comment: @IRTFM thanks. Since we need to pass the coordinates of both x and y, I thought it will more difficult to use segments. However,  I will take a look at if segments can help me with this.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out the logic of your nested for-loops and the size of your data setup was intimidating. Would have been easier (for me) if you had just presented 5 or 6 points and clors and said what you wnated from them. Segments requires x&y for both starting and stopping and then allows a separate color for that segment.. It's pretty easy to turn a sequence of x&y's into the two sequences of starts and stops. For the x's just index the original series using `head(x,-1)` and `tail(x, -1)`. Unlike jmcarter9t, I find that base plotting is easier to employ for special cases like yours.

Comment: @IRTFM you are right. I must have included only a small portion of what I have in my mind. For the next questions, I will take this into consideration. I was trying to plot the time series of my data which I put into an array of 3x5x100. That's why I was using nested for loops; "i" for rows and "j" for columns... I will look into the segment and update it here if I can solve my problem with it. Thanks for your valuable insights, it is very helpful.

Comment: @jmcarter9t actually I have started plotting the data with ggplot2. Although I am not an advanced user of it, I frequently use ggplot2 whenever possible. However, in this specific case, I lose the flexibility to adjust the plot according to my needs when I use ggplot2.